# bootstrap panels + media layout for comment layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a layout like the following (or some minor variation)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  --------------------------------------------------------------- |
|  | ----=----- ------------------------------------------------ | |
|  | |        | |                                              | | |
|  | | image  | |              info                            | | |
|  | ---------- ------------------------------------------------ | |
|  | |------------------------------------------------------------ |
|  | |                                                           | |
|  | |       Some body                                           | |
|  |  ------------------------------------------------------------ |
|   ----------------------------------------------------------------

      ... continued
```

For a comment thread. I dont plan on doing threaded comments. Just a linear comment thread.

Bootstrap provides the `media` class and I can do `media-left` to position the image and using `media-heading` / `media-body` to almost get the layout I want.

But, the heading / body will be positioned to the side of the image. No good.

I was attempting to mix panels and media. Media to position the image / heading (which would be info secton here) and the panel for the comment body / footer for button / links to reply etc.

Really I just wanted to include panels because it provides a nice border / styling outlining the body, which I'd like to include.

So, far they haven't been playing nice together. One will overflow the other be misaligned etc. Haven't found a decent way to get this layout to work.

Almost the layout I want using panels / thumbnails:

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/2gZVzw2l90)

The panel styling makes this look hideous. Hence, trying to keep the general layout but modify the styling with the mixed classes / template.

Is there a way to mix the media classes and panels to get the layout above?

So the image / info would be the media / media-left / media-body and the body section would be panel / panel-body / panel-footer. Every way I've tried overflow horribly.

Edit: Included html of bootply of close layout to meet "quality standards" before someone comments

```
<div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="row flex-container">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg">
          <div class="caption">
            <p>A captuion</p>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-10">
         <p>
           <span class="pull-left">By: <a href="#">A User</a></span>
           <span class="pull-right">A timestamp</span>
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <p>A random body</p>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer">
    <p>Some footer</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, are you aware that panels are removed in BS 4? No biggie but just saying maybe you could work this out in a more future proof way. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: I haven't looked much at bs 4 yet. It's still in alpha and not officially released yet right? Was going to wait to go to bs4 when it was out of alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my suggestion was that you use simply some html and css to accomplish this?

Using bootstrap it's quite easy to make that "responsive". As a plus it's more future proof this way isn't it?

Here is my work of art: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17945/

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    background: #efe;
    color: red;
}
.container {
  background: #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: none;
  border: red solid 1px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
.comment-footer-container {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.comment-footer {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}
.comment-footer p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <p class="text-center">
        <small>A Caption</small>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
      <h5>Some Heading</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h5>Another Heading</h5>
      <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
    <p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 comment-footer-container">
      <div class="comment-footer">
        <p class="text-center">Some footer</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found one way to get the layout I wanted. Markup needs some work, but rough idea is there

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/zC83US0Nck#)

sample html:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="row flex-container">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="media-left">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg" />
          <div class="caption visible-xs"><p>Commenter Name</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
      <div class="media-heading">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p><span class="pull-left hidden-xs">Commenter Name</span> Timestamp</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6"><a><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>0 Likes</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Some comment body text here.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-footer">
    <span>Some buttons or something here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```